# SUMIFS syntax issue

Tags: excel-formula

```
=SUMIFS($E$10:$E$21,$D$10:$D$21,">="&B1,"<"&B2,"'=0")
```

"There's a problem with this formula.
Trying to type a formula?"

I don't believe the first criteria are wrong, is the 'equals 0' the issue?

Comment: try `=SUMIFS($E$10:$E$21,$D$10:$D$21,">="&B1,$D$10:$D$21,"<"&B2,$D$10:$D$21,"'=0")` presume you are comparing all criteria with range `$D$10:$D$21`

Comment: you could just give `0` instead of `"=0"`. Also the second and third criteria range is not provided as stated in the above comment

Comment: @TerryW please don't answer questions in comments. That's what answers are for. Please post it as an answer, so it can be marked and later found by other people. If you leave it as a comment, nothing can be marked as an answer. If you feel it does not warrant an answer, vote to close it, but don't answer in a comment. Note the placeholder text in the comment that starts wit `Avoid ...` It's there for a reason.

Comment: Can you post a data sample for the "isn't zero" scenario? Please edit your question to do that, then post a comment for people who are following the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sumifs() needs pairs of range and condition text for each condition.

Also, the conditions are combined with an AND logic.

```
=SUMIFS($E$10:$E$21,$D$10:$D$21,">="&B1,$D$10:$D$21,"<"&B2,$D$10:$D$21,0)
```

If you want OR logic, use three separate SUMIF and add them all up.